# What is the value of the fourth cohomology class of $\mathrm{Co}_0$ induced by the 24-dimensional representation?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

The group $\mathrm{Co}_0$ has a 24-dimensional module.  This induces a map $\mathrm H^4(O(24),\mathbb Z) \to \mathrm H^4(\mathrm{Co}_0,\mathbb Z)$.  Has this map been computed? Has the right hand side been computed? Where can I learn how to do these types of computations?

Comment: This paper might have some relevance. Geoffrey Mason, Reed–Muller codes, the fourth cohomology group of a finite group, and the β-invariant,J. Algebra 312, Issue 1, 1 June 2007, Pages 218-227.

Comment: The domain is ZxZ/2, with first factor generated by p1 and second factor by the Bockstein of w1w2.  If you think the same question for H^{1,2,3} is easy, we can focus on p1. I bet the codomain is unknown, I don't know why.  But you can start by restricting the rep. to easy subgroups.  In general there's a split injection of H4(G;Z_p) into H4(p-Sylow;Z_p), which is Z/p for p=11,13,23. For p=7 the Sylow is Z/pxZ/p, likely easy. The 2-Sylow is complicated, but it's the same as the 2-Sylow of the normalizer of a Z/2^12-subgroup -- with known H4? I don't know how far this train goes.

Comment: @DavidTreumann great. I really only want to know the image of p1. Benson has worked out all details for p=2, I think, but I don't know much and so didn't try to understand his answer. I'll look again.

Comment: @DavidTreumann H^1(Co0) = H^2(Co0) = 0, so that should handle the easier factors